# Make Dynamics CRM 2011 field readonly NOT disabled

Tags: javascript, crm, microsoft-dynamics, xrm

I would like to make a inputfield readonly. I am familiar with the setDisabled() method in XRM, the downside of this method is that it is not possible to copy/paste values from the fields.

Is there another way then using javascript/jQuery directly  to set the readonly property on the field by using it's field name?

Kind regards 
Rim

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery to do this:

```
$("#element").attr("readonly" , "readonly");
```

Comment: Hi Alaa SKHRIA,
Thank you for tyou answer. This is what i am currently doing. But it doesn't feel right. I am looking for a XRM way of doing it (If there is one)